# Finding shops in Dwarf Fortress Adventure Mode

Tags: dwarf-fortress-adventure

I have been trying to teach myself how to play for a while and am using the Phoebus texture pack. I'm having difficulty finding shops in even the yellow regions (I've only found one in my 15 or so lives)

Answer (score 1):

Shops appear in big cities ( the ones bordered by fortifications ). Otherwise in little hamlets; it's quite deserted. Choose the "Capital" option in conversation and you'll be told how to get to the capital. Or use the Q map option to find the big cities.